# test connection failed in websphere-DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456

Tags: datasource, websphere-8

I created a data source on my local WAS.The database I am trying to connect is on a dev sql server 2012 host.When I do a test connection it fails with below error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user ''.
>   ClientConnectionId:c1c4d500-ad7c-4014-b9c2-96e8f54e4a3f DSRA0010E: SQL
>   State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456 [7/18/18 13:18:51:387 IST] 00000061
>   SystemErr     R   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>   [7/18/18 13:18:51:387 IST] 00000061 SystemErr     R   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
>   [7/18/18 13:18:51:387 IST] 00000061 SystemErr     R   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84

Any help in how can I resolve this?

Comment: Really hard to tell without more information. Do you have the DataSource configured to use a JAAS authentication alias?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are trying to connect without a user name specified.

Check your configuration to see if you have specified user/password on the data source or a valid authentication alias.  The following
[knowledge center doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tdat_testcon.html) lists the precedence for determining the user/password that are used for test connection operations.